# How did Zwicky discover dark matter?

Tags: history, dark-matter, galaxy-rotation-curve, virial-theorem, galaxy-clusters

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fritz_Zwicky#Dark_matter) Zwicky used "virial theorem" to discover the gravitational anomaly in the Coma Galaxy cluster. But I also remember reading that he used Kepler's third law. Which one is correct?

Comment: Kepler's third law does only hold for a point-like central mass, not for a continuous mass distribution – so it can't be applied to the rotation curves of galaxies.

Comment: I assume here "rotation" refers to the motion of the helical arms of the galaxy. Is this motion outward or inward? Is there a simple beginners' tutorial kind of book or article on this subject?

Comment: No one has discovered dark matter.  We only know the existing theories do not fit the observed facts.  Dark matter (in various proposed forms) is one explanation for these issues.

Comment: @SebastianRiese It seems that Vera Rubin used Kepler's Third https://www.wondriumdaily.com/vera-rubin-the-rotation-curve-and-the-first-ever-evidence-of-dark-matter/#:~:text=When%20Vera%20Rubin%20began%20studying,rotation%20curve%20was%20strangely%20flat.

Comment: @zeynel That's not what's written in the article. The article just tells about the *expected* rotation curve in the absence of Dark matter, where Kepler's third law is expected to hold roughly far out from the galactic center (because there's very little visible matter there compared to the galactic core, so you would assume **roughly** Keplerian orbits around the far away central mass of the galaxy). In this way my first comment was a bit too restrictive – but it still holds: You can't naïvely expect Kepler's third law to hold for the rotation curves of galaxies.

Comment: Zwicky's analysis didn't deal with rotation curves (or "helical arms") at all. He was looking at the projected velocities of multiple _galaxies_ in the Coma Cluster, and working out whether or not the whole cluster should have flown apart if the mass was entirely due to the sum total of all the stars in all the galaxies. (The answer seemed to be "yes"; since the cluster is still there and _hasn't_ flown apart, the suggestion was that there was a lot more "dark" mass present.)

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately the original paper is German
https://articles.adsabs.harvard.edu//full/1933AcHPh...6..110Z/0000110.000.html

But Wikipedia (for Fritz Zwicky) translates what I believe to be a snippet of the paper or maybe a part of the abstract:

> In order to obtain an average Doppler effect of 1000 km/s or more, as observed, the average density in the Coma system would thus have to be at least 400 times greater than that derived on the basis of observations of luminous matter. If this were to be verified, the surprising result would then follow that dark matter is present in very much greater density than luminous matter.

Then this paper from Zwicky four years later does mention the Virial theorem
https://adsabs.harvard.edu/full/1937ApJ....86..217Z, but he's also using several other methods in the same paper to come up with a variety of estimates for the mass. But a key phrase seems to be "the application of [the virial theorem] to the Coma cluster leads to a minimum value of 4.5X10^10 solar masses for the average mass of its member nebulae"

And this review paper
https://arxiv.org/abs/1703.00013
phrases it as

> Zwicky found the velocity dispersion
> of its members to be so high that, to keep the system stable, the average mass density
> in the Coma system would have to be much higher than that deduced from observed
> visible matter.

All in all it seems likely that the original paper used the virial theorem - it's quite general, even if the galaxy isn't in a steady state. It's just saying - we need to have more potential energy than kinetic energy or the galaxy is in the middle of flying apart rapidly.

Comment: "or the galaxy is in the middle of flying apart rapidly" -- or, in this case, the *galaxy cluster* is in the middle of flying apart.